# Android Studio can't find R.layout.simple_list_item_1, or any other default layout IDs

Tags: android

IDs for things like `R.layout.simple_list_item_1` don't show up on autocompletion in Android Studio. Nor can they be resolved when the name is typed in manually. I'm trying to use an ArrayAdapter, and I had to manually create a `simple_list_item_1.xml` in my project layout directory, and paste in the contents from the [Android repository on Github](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml)

Am I missing something, or is that what's supposed to be done? Most resources I go to seem to just reference the list item XML without doing anything else

Comment: That showed up as suggested, so I thought it had to do with Android lol

Comment: @AlexYan Have you tried `Clean` and `Rebuilt`?

Comment: Yep. Turns out there's an `android.R` that I had to import... I've never seen that...

Comment: @Try_me34 R is a programming language

Comment: @popovitsj since we are in `android` tag I would assume OP is referring to the `library`, which came up to be the case..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

to use android predefined layouts, colors etc. You should use

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

probably you try to reach your own resources. Check your imports and you should see your R file.

Comment: You should **NOT** import `android.R`. You should use the fully qualified name `android.R.layout.whatever`, so that it is clear when reading the code that you are referring to an android resource, not your own.

Answer (score 5):

as @Orhan Obut explained, use

`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`.

**Do NOT** leave out the word android in the above statement. That is how you access android's predefined resources

Answer (score 1):

It's two years later but never too late because I spent the day reading all posts about this and the answer on the Android Developer [site](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html) was simple: make sure the google depository is installed for your project in the repositories section of its build.gradle:

```
maven {
    url "https://maven.google.com"
}
```

Worked for me as soon as the project was synched after adding the .

Comment: Well, for a moment it seemed to have cleared all the red flags until during the build attempt: Error:(71, 37) error: no suitable constructor

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. The error was resolved when I imported android.R.layout and typed layout.simple_list_item_1 instead of R.layout.simple_list_item_1.