# android.R.layout.simple_list_item.x not found in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I was trying to implement `ListView` in Android Studio with `ArrayAdapter<String>`,but there is no suggestion for this by the Android Studio. After [looking at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253738/android-studio-cant-find-r-layout-simple-list-item-1-or-any-other-default-layo), I tried to do , `android.R.layout.simple_list_item1` and still no success. There is no suggestion even when I type `android.R` explicitly.

P.S. I am using Android Studio 1.2.2.

Comment: post your classes and xml files

Comment: well, I just added the file manually as the other post suggested and all the other simple_list_item.x appeared automatically. Plus I also build cleaned the project after adding the file.